# Scrollable, uneditable, updatable text

Tags: java, text, label, scrollable

I'm new to Java and I started a little RPG game. When a battle starts, I would like to display the battle messages in a little box. I would like the box to be scrolled automatically, displaying the new message every time, and not losing the old messages.

Comment: What research have you done / things have you tried so far?

Additionally, what does "not losing the old messages" entail?

Comment: You explained it fine but i doesn't see the code that explain what have you did till now

Comment: I tried using JLabel,Textmessage and adding messages to them everytime, the problem is that the list of messages gets too long .
and by not losing the old messages I mean when I scroll up I can see some of the old messages. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

I am going to give you the information you need, but it is your duty to figure out how to use them:
1-you should use a JTextArea to display your messages.
2-when a new message come, use the append() function on you JTextArea object (use \n to return automatically in line).
3-add a JScrollPane to your JTextArea so it can be scrollable.
4-update you caret automatically to always show the last message printed use this where myJTA is your JTextArea:

```
DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret)myJTA.getCaret();
caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);
```

now you have all the pieces of the puzzle. 
Good luck.

EDIT:
if you want your JTextArea not editable use:

```
myJTA.setEdtable(false);
```